# how to use jquery with slick slider in angular4

Tags: jquery, html, angular, slick.js

I want to use testimonial jquery code in my angular 4 application but I don't know how to use it in my application .What I've done so far ...

I have a **jquery code** like this

```
var clSlickSlider = function() {

        $('.clients').slick({
            arrows: false,
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 6,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            //autoplay: true,
            pauseOnFocus: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 1000,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1200,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 5
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 1000,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 4
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 800,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 500,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2
                    }
                }

            ]
        });

        $('.testimonials').slick({
            arrows: true,
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            pauseOnFocus: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 1500,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 900,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 800,
                    settings: {
                        arrows: false,
                        dots: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

    };
```

and corresponding **html code** is

```
 < div class="row clients-testimonials" data-aos="fade-up">
 <div class="testimonials">

                    <div class="testimonials__slide">

                        <p>Qui ipsam temporibus quisquam vel. Maiores eos cumque distinctio nam accusantium ipsum. 
                        Laudantium quia consequatur molestias delectus culpa facere hic dolores aperiam. Accusantium quos qui praesentium corpori.
                        Excepturi nam cupiditate culpa doloremque deleniti repellat.</p>

                        <img src="images/avatars/user-01.jpg" alt="Author image" class="testimonials__avatar">
                        <div class="testimonials__info">
                            <span class="testimonials__name">Tim Cook</span> 
                            <span class="testimonials__pos">CEO, Apple</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="testimonials__slide">

                        <p>Excepturi nam cupiditate culpa doloremque deleniti repellat. Veniam quos repellat voluptas animi adipisci.
                        Nisi eaque consequatur. Quasi voluptas eius distinctio. Atque eos maxime. Qui ipsam temporibus quisquam vel.</p>

                        <img src="images/avatars/user-05.jpg" alt="Author image" class="testimonials__avatar">
                        <div class="testimonials__info">
                            <span class="testimonials__name">Sundar Pichai</span> 
                            <span class="testimonials__pos">CEO, Google</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="testimonials__slide">

                        <p>Repellat dignissimos libero. Qui sed at corrupti expedita voluptas odit. Nihil ea quia nesciunt. Ducimus aut sed ipsam.  
                        Autem eaque officia cum exercitationem sunt voluptatum accusamus. Quasi voluptas eius distinctio.</p>

                        <img src="images/avatars/user-02.jpg" alt="Author image" class="testimonials__avatar">
                        <div class="testimonials__info">
                            <span class="testimonials__name">Satya Nadella</span> 
                            <span class="testimonials__pos">CEO, Microsoft</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div><!-- end testimonials -->

            </div> <!-- end col-full -->
        </div> <!-- end client-testimonials -->

    </section> <!-- end s-clients --<div class="col-full">
```

Now I want to integrate that Jquery code into my application , It would be helpful if someone provide me a way to do that.

Comment: I see html and jquery... but where's your angular code...?

Comment: that's  what i am not aware how to use jquery in angular4

Answer (score 1):

Create shared component for slick slider and use it.

```
  import {Component, Input, ElementRef, AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';
    declare var jQuery: any;

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-slick-slider',
        template: `
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        `,
        styles: []
    })

    export class SlickSliderComponent implements AfterContentInit {
        @Input() options: any;
        $element: any;
        @Input() isLoad = false;
        defaultOptions: any = {
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 400,
            slidesToShow: 6,
            slidesToScroll: 6,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1024,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 4,
                        slidesToScroll: 4,
                        infinite: true,
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 600,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 3
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2
                    }
                }]
        };

        constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
        }

        ngAfterContentInit(): void {
            for (const key in this.options) {
                if (key) {
                    this.defaultOptions[key] = this.options[key];
                }
            }
            this.$element = jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).slick(this.defaultOptions);
        }
    }
```

**HTML**
`slickSliderOptions` is optional. if you want to overwrite default option that time you need to pass

```
   <app-slick-slider [options]="slickSliderOptions" class="slick-slider">
code here ...
</app-slick-slider>
```

**angular-cli**

```
 "styles": [ "../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss",
        "../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss"]

 "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]
```

**Note:** make sure you have jQuery installed

Comment: declare var $ :any ;